# .htacces Redirect strange behavior

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, web, http-redirect

im currently moving mt website temporally to other domain. For that reason, I decided to make a 302 redirect using my .htaccess file.

Here's the .htaccess file

```
Redirect 302 / https://newDomain.herokuapp.com/
```

The problem is that when I try to access to my old website it redirect me to

```
https://newDomain.herokuapp.com/~aerotec.daemon/
```

My question is why does "~aerotec.daemon/" is added to the end of the new URL

Comment: Is that something done by the Heroku app itself? Nothing in the .htaccess file would cause that.

Comment: Thanks @MattClark, do you know how can I specific access to index.html on Heroku ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Heroku, I just know that apache / htaccess would not do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added #page-top to the end of Redirect

```
Redirect 302 / https://newDomain.herokuapp.com/#page-top
```

It still add "~aerotec.daemon/" to the end but now it loads the index page